# PHP PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My Query:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ptd_users (username,contact,email,longitude,latitude,state,city,address) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
$q = $conn->prepare($query);
$q->execute($_POST['user']);
```

Result of `print_r($_POST[user])` :

```
Array ( [name] => marc [contact] => 123456789 [email] => marc@gmail.com [longitude] => 12.3786085 [latitude] => 96.6126145 [state_select] => Arizona [city_select] => sussex [address] => address details )
```

I'm getting the following error while executing the query:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Comment: Try `$q->execute(array($_POST['user']['name'], $_POST['user']['contact'], ..., $_POST['user']['address']));`
Replace this `...` with the rest of your $_POST :)

Comment: Thats the same array as `$_POST['user']`

Comment: Look over a tutorial for mysqli

Comment: @lmarcelocc: wouldn't that be a lot painful in case one has a large amount of post vars?

Comment: @Mihai: I don't understand how does that would solve the issue in hand?

Comment: @popla, yes it is! But you can conctruct an array and then sending it in the `$q->execute($myArray);` method. And, if your expected some other types then just `strings`, its a good pratice to `bind` them like  
`$conn->bindParam(2, $_POST['user']['contact'],PDO::PARAM_INT);`
But @Rizier123 example gives you a better perspective :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only bind 1 parameter to 8 placeholders, so that is not going to work. Now you have 3 ways to solve this:

1. Access the single array elements and bind them like this:

```
$q->execute($_POST['user']['name'], $_POST['user']['contact'], $_POST['user']['email'], $_POST['user']['longitude'], $_POST['user']['latitude'], $_POST['user']['state_select'], $_POST['user']['city_select'], $_POST['user']['address'] );
```

2. Use placeholders with names like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ptd_users (username,contact,email,longitude,latitude,state,city,address) values (:name, :contact, :email, :longitude, :latitude, :state_select, :city_select, :address)";
```

And then you can use your associative array like this:

```
$q->execute($_POST['user']);
```

3. Use Positional placeholders like this:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO ptd_users (username,contact,email,longitude,latitude,state,city,address) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
```

And then you can change your associative array to numeric array like this:

```
$q->execute(array_values($_POST['user']));
```

Comment: What's wrong with un-named placeholders like "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"  ?

Comment: @popla Nothing, but If you use a associative array how should it know which array element should be binded with which placeholder?! That's why you have to use every element as single parameter or use placeholder with names, so that it can use the indexes of the array to bind the values

Comment: Yes that sounds reasonable. But then there's a glitch too, I mean then under which circumstances the un-named placeholders are going to be used? I'm pretty new to PDO, clarifying this would be very much helpful for me. Thanks.

Comment: I have given a try to the second method. But that's inserting ':name', ':contact', ':email', ':longitude', ':latitude', ':state_select', ':city_select', ':address' in my table as is.

Comment: @popla That's a good question :D If you use positional placeholders (`?`) Then the order how you bind the parameters matters! so first value which you bind will be replaced with the first question mark and so on... If you use named placeholders(`:name`) Then the order doesn't matter you just have to make sure that you have a associative array with the named placeholders as keys

Comment: @popla Ah forgot to remove the quotes in the second example, try it again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71870/discussion-between-popla-and-rizier123).